# Dealing four hands

Tags: java, heap-memory

The program deal four is supposed to create a shuffled deck and deal four hands of 13 cards from the deck.

I keep getting an `out of memory error` at `cards[i] = Card(x);` in the `DealFour` class. I attempted to increase the maximum heap space through the java `-Xmx` argument. This does not work.

Here is the Card class

```
package Casino;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class Card extends Object
{
    String[] deck = {"AH", "KH", "QH", "JH", "10H", "9H", "8H", "7H", "6H", "5H", "4H", "3H", "2H",
                     "AS", "KS", "QS", "JS", "10S", "9S", "8S", "7S", "6S", "5S", "4S", "3S", "2S",
                     "AD", "KD", "QD", "JD", "10D", "9D", "8D", "7D", "6D", "5D", "4D", "3D", "2D",
                     "AC", "KC", "QC", "JC", "10C", "9C", "8C", "7C", "6C", "5C", "4C", "3C", "2C"};

    String card;


    public Card(int i)
    {
        card = deck[i];
    }

    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println(card);
    }
}
```

And Here is the `DealFour` class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import Casino.*;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class DealFour
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Stack shuffledDeck = new Stack();
        Random repeater = new Random();
        Card[] cards = new Card[52];

        int high = 52;

        for(int i = 0; i < 52;)
        {
            int x = Math.abs(repeater.nextInt(52));
            if(x<52)
            {
                cards[i] = new Card(x);
                if(i==0)
                {
                    shuffledDeck.push(cards[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    for(int w = 0; w < i;)
                    {
                        int q = (int)(i-1);
                        if(w==q)
                        {
                            shuffledDeck.push(cards[i]);
                            i++;
                        }
                        if(cards[w]!=cards[i])
                        {
                            w++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Card[] hand1 = new Card[13];
        Card[] hand2 = new Card[13];
        Card[] hand3 = new Card[13];
        Card[] hand4 = new Card[13];

        System.out.println("Hand 1");
        for(int x = 0; x < 13; x++)
        {
            hand1[x] = (Card)shuffledDeck.pop();
            hand1[x].show();
            hand2[x] = (Card)shuffledDeck.pop();
            hand3[x] = (Card)shuffledDeck.pop();
            hand4[x] = (Card)shuffledDeck.pop();
        }

        System.out.println("Hand 2");
        for(int y = 0; y < 13; y++)
        {
            hand2[y].show();
        }

        System.out.println("Hand 3");
        for(int z = 0; z < 13; z++)
        {
            hand3[z].show();
        }

        System.out.println("Hand 4");
        for(int g = 0; g < 13; g++)
        {
            hand4[g].show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the exact error you get? Please post that including the trace. As a general guess, you might be running infinite loops, since your for-loops look somewhat tangles up (and you should replace them with while-loops, since you're using them as while-loops). Also, your if-check (x<52) is unnecessary.

Comment: side note: `extends Object` is unnecessary. Every class you create extends `Object` automatically.

Comment: Your inner loop `for(int w = 0; w < i;)` never ends, too: `w` starts at a value less than `i`, and then both values get incremented on each step of the loop. Since the loop pushes a card onto a stack at each iteration, you get an out of memory instead of an infinite loop.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at Casino.Card.<init>(Card.java:6)
 at DealFour.main(DealFour.java:25)

Comment: I only add a card if w is one less than i or if i is 0. One question about the inner loop though, Does w automatically reset to zero when i is changed and the outer loop starts over or should I add that?

Answer (score 3):

You've created an infinite loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 52;) {
  int x = Math.abs(repeater.nextInt(52)); // no need for Math.abs, this
                                          // result is always positive
  if (x < 52) { // note: this if is redundant

    cards[i] = new Card(x);
    if (i == 0) { // <--------------- this is always true
      shuffledDeck.push(cards[i]);
    } else {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

You never increment `i`, so the loop never ends. The only increment operation is buried inside your `else` clause which will never execute.

I suspect this is homework or a self-study exercise, so I'll refrain from trying to fix anything else. Hopefully this hint is enough to get you working towards a solution.